# Correspondence between 3D and 2D points using Least-Squares struggles with a simple problem

Tags: python, numpy, projection, least-squares, scipy-optimize

I am trying to estimate a projection matrix between 3D and 2D points using least-squares method.

I am using a dummy 3D data, from which I am taking the same X and Y and translating X by 3 points/pixels. Despite a simple translation along the X axis, the non-linear least squares `scipy.optimize.least_squares` struggles to estimate a projection matrix. Am I doing something wrong or should I approach the problem differently?

[image]

Here is a standalone Python code with dummy 2D and 3D data

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import least_squares
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

initial_guess_K = np.array([[ 500,   0, 535],
                            [   0, 500, 390],
                            [   0,   0,  -1]])

initial_guess_R_T = np.array([[ 0.5,   -1,  0],
                            [   0,    0, -1],
                            [   1,  0.5,  0]])

initial_guess_I_t = np.array([[   1,    0, 0, 300],
                              [   0,    1, 0, 300],
                              [   0,    0, 1,  30]])

initial_guess_P = np.matmul(initial_guess_K, np.matmul(initial_guess_R_T, initial_guess_I_t))


translate_x = 3
points_3d = np.random.randint(500, size=(50, 3))
#2D same as 3D, only translated by 3 points in x direction and without Z dimension
points_2d = np.column_stack((np.array(points_3d[:,0:1] + translate_x, dtype=int), points_3d[:,1:2]))

#project 3D point onto 2D
def projection(P, points_3d):
    p_1 = P[0, :]
    p_2 = P[1, :]
    p_3 = P[2, :]
    projected_points_2d = []
    for n in range(points_3d.shape[0]):
        points = points_3d[n, :]
        if points.shape[0] == 3:
            points = np.concatenate((points, np.array([1])))
        x = np.sum(p_1*points) / np.sum(p_3*points)
        y = np.sum(p_2*points) / np.sum(p_3*points)
        projected_points_2d.append([x, y])
    return np.array(projected_points_2d)

#lsq objective function
def objective_func(x, **kwargs):
    x = np.concatenate((x, np.array([1])))
    P = np.array([x[0:4], x[4:8], x[8:12]])

    points_2d = kwargs['pts2d']
    points_3d = kwargs['pts3d']
    proj = projection(P, points_3d)

    diff = proj - points_2d
    return diff.flatten()

#function to run least squares optimisation
def least_sq(pts2d, pts3d, initial_guess):
    dic = {}
    dic['pts2d'] = pts2d
    dic['pts3d'] = pts3d
    ls = least_squares(objective_func, initial_guess.flatten()[:11], method='lm', verbose=2, max_nfev=50000, loss='linear', kwargs=dic)
    M = np.concatenate((ls.x, np.array([1])))
    M = M.reshape((3, 4))

    return M

#return 2d points and calculate residual
def evaluate_points(P, points_2d, points_3d):
    estimated_points_2d = projection(P, points_3d)

    residual = np.sum(np.hypot(estimated_points_2d[:,0] - points_2d[:, 0], 
                               estimated_points_2d[:,1] - points_2d[:, 1]))
    return estimated_points_2d, residual

#visualise real and estimated 2D points
def visualize_points_image(actual_pts, projected_pts):
    _, ax = plt.subplots()

    ax.scatter(actual_pts[:, 0], actual_pts[:, 1], c='red', marker='o',
        label='Actual points')
    ax.scatter(projected_pts[:, 0], projected_pts[:, 1], c='green', marker='+',
        label='Projected points')
    ax.set_ylim([0,500])
    ax.set_xlim([0,500])

    ax.legend()
    plt.show()


P = least_sq(points_2d, points_3d, initial_guess_P)

[projected_2d_pts, residual] = evaluate_points(P, points_2d, points_3d);

print ("Residual", residual)

visualize_points_image(points_2d, projected_2d_pts)
```

**EDIT:** I tried the linear least-squares solution too (`np.linalg.lstsq(X, Y)`) and it works fine for translations and scaling, but fails when translations are scaling is non-linear, for example when:

```
import random
translate = random.randint(20, 50)
translate2 = random.randint(0, 10)
scale = random.random()
scale2 = random.random()*2
points_3d = np.random.randint(500, size=(50, 3))
#apply translation and scaling to xs < 250 and different translation and scaling to xs > 250
points_2d = np.column_stack(([item*scale+translate if item[0] < 250 else item*scale2+translate2 for item in points_3d[:,0:1]], 
                            np.array(points_3d[:,1:2] * scale + translate, dtype=int)))

n = points_3d.shape[0]
pad = lambda x: np.hstack([x, np.ones((x.shape[0], 1))])
unpad = lambda x: x[:,:-1]
X = pad(points_3d)
Y = pad(points_2d)

A, res, rank, s = np.linalg.lstsq(X, Y)

transform = lambda x: unpad(np.dot(pad(x), A))

visualize_points_image(points_2d, transform(points_3d))
```

[image]

Comment: Is there some reason you aren't using a linear least squares solution?

Comment: @MadPhysicist Because there will be translations, rotations, and distortions (e.g. fisheye and composite image projections) applied to the 3D points later. Translation by 3 points is simply an example

Comment: You can fit an around Affine transform or any other matrix representing a linear transformation using linear least squares

Comment: @MadPhysicist I have just tried using `numpy.linalg.lstsq`. While it works on the dummy data with random translations and scaling, it gives large error on the data that comes from the points in the distorted and stitched images